# Volley POST string request unexpected error 500

Tags: php, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

I am using Volley library in my project and getting `Unexpected response code 500` as response.

I have searched stackoverflow thoroughly and still unable to find solution that works.

Following is my code for making GET string request

```java
        val API = "http://squadtechsolution.com/android/v1/allcompany.php"
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mActivity)
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            API,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                Log.i("dxdiag", response)
                mView.onFetchHttpDataResult(true)
                Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.i("dxdiag", error.printStackTrace().toString())
                mView.onFetchHttpDataResult(false)
            })
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
```

Following is the stacktrace

```
2019-09-03 17:15:53.237 3308-3892/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp 
E/Volley: [194] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 
500 for 
http://squadtechsolution.com/android/v1/allcompany.php
2019-09-03 17:15:53.243 3308-3351/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7d84180: ver 2 0 (tinfo 
0xa7d832b0)
2019-09-03 17:15:53.256 3308-3308/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp 
W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
2019-09-03 17:15:53.257 3308-3308/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp 
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:205)2019-09-03 17:15:53.257 3308-3308/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)2019-09-03 17:15:53.257 3308-3308/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)2019-09-03 17:15:53.257 3308-3308/com.squadtechs.markhor.foodapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

**Following is PHP code that I wrote on server side:**

```php
<?php
    require 'db.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `company_profile`";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $id=$row['id']; 

        $company_name=$row['company_name'];
        $cuisine=$row['cuisine'];
        $conpany_phone=$row['conpany_phone'];
        $company_description=$row['company_description']; 
        $company_logo=$row['company_logo'];
        $company_type=$row['company_type'];
        $delivery_type=$row['delivery_type'];
        $delivery_range=$row['delivery_range']; 
        $delivery_fee=$row['delivery_fee'];
        $delivery_pickupinfo=$row['delivery_pickupinfo'];
        $address=$row['address'];

        $companyData[] = array('id'=> $id,'company_name'=> 
        $company_name,'cuisine'=> $cuisine,'conpany_phone'=> 
        $conpany_phone,'company_description'=> 
        $company_description,'company_logo'=> $company_logo,'company_type'=> 
        $company_type,'delivery_type'=> $delivery_type,'delivery_range'=> 
        $delivery_range,'delivery_fee'=> 
        $delivery_fee,'delivery_pickupinfo'=> $delivery_pickupinfo,'address'=> $address);   
    }
    echo $jsonformat=json_encode($companyData);
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: make sure you are sending all params in request

Comment: Would you please share the Postman request screenshot with your question?

Comment: and where is the server-side code, that returns HTTP 500 ?? That an IDE update causes this is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @MartinZeitler here you go, I have added php code as well

Comment: This does not match the URL logcat is showing.

Comment: Ooh sorry @MartinZeitler, I forgot to update logcate, let me edit that one as well

Comment: You said that you want to send a POST request, but your code does a GET request.

Comment: Ooh..sorry..it is GET actually

Comment: please share the `Generate Code Snippet` value from postman by clicking the `Code` on the right hand side of the software.

Comment: Will do after I get back home

Comment: got the chance to check the postman?

Comment: can you please explain where to find this option?

Comment: I'll ask you to follow a simple step to check the origin of the problem. Create a simple Android project with single Activity and check if it still returns `Unexpected response code 500` as a response? I just checked your exact code it returns a response without a problem. And tell me your Volley version, please.

Comment: Second option: To test whether it's because of the conversion problem not. Delete everything in your PHP file and replace with `<?php 
   
// Declare an array  
$value = array( 
    "name"=>"GFG", 
    "email"=>"abc@gfg.com"); 
   
// Use json_encode() function 
$json = json_encode($value); 
   
// Display the output 
echo($json); 
   
?> ` if it doesn't throw an error, then you'll have to make changes in your PHP file to properly encode your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code a bit and checked it in postman, it works fine.

I moved the JSON encode statment out of the if statement.

```
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $id=$row['id']; 

    $company_name=$row['company_name'];
    $cuisine=$row['cuisine'];
    $conpany_phone=$row['conpany_phone'];
    $company_description=$row['company_description']; 
    $company_logo=$row['company_logo'];
    $company_type=$row['company_type'];
    $delivery_type=$row['delivery_type'];
    $delivery_range=$row['delivery_range']; 
    $delivery_fee=$row['delivery_fee'];
    $delivery_pickupinfo=$row['delivery_pickupinfo'];
    $address=$row['address'];

    $companyData[] = array('id'=> $id,'company_name'=> 
    $company_name,'cuisine'=> $cuisine,'conpany_phone'=> 
    $conpany_phone,'company_description'=> 
    $company_description,'company_logo'=> $company_logo,'company_type'=> 
    $company_type,'delivery_type'=> $delivery_type,'delivery_range'=> 
    $delivery_range,'delivery_fee'=> 
    $delivery_fee,'delivery_pickupinfo'=> $delivery_pickupinfo,'address'=> $address);   
}
echo $jsonformat=json_encode($companyData);

$conn->close();
```

Comment: great that it helped

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line from your server-side code and check

```
echo $jsonformat=json_encode($companyData);
```

and the same is not working on postman also

[image]

Comment: let me check this

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code `500` represents the `internal server error`, clearly states that you don't have any issue in client-side (here in your case `Volly`) but the issue is at server-side. Try debugging your server-side php code. the code is not properly executing and hence it's returning the `500 internal server error` in Http response header. `Volly` just thrown the received header as an error.

If you are backend dev, you should try it first with `REST Clients` before integration with the mobile application. You can get it one from [Here](https://www.getpostman.com/). Your API should be well tested and should be in a working state otherwise you will receive errors all the time.

Comment: open your server directory and look for the `.errorlog` file, the error will be dumped there. can you post it here? because it's server-side error and I'm sure about it.

Comment: I just noticed that postman also gives same error but in quite hidden manner

Comment: you can post it here, or give me an error screen image, please. it would be best if you can post the `.errorlog` file from server

Comment: I think missing any parameter while the response to client-side. response array data miss any parameter. check database too for valid entry in database

Comment: you can check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500  you are missing something, but what did you miss? to find it out check the server-side code or post the log here. However, the `php` code you have posted is not complete code so it's difficult to find out the bug.

Comment: I believe something is wrong with php code I wrote but as I am not a php developer, I can't actually debug it properly, would you be kind enough to look at my php code??

Comment: Sure, I'm pretty fluent with it. Please post the `.php` file

Comment: @KiranManiya,Why you're insisting it's a backend problem when OP says backend operates properly :) ? Just post the given URL in Postman you'll get a response with `200` response code. I've tried it and got a proper response.

Comment: @Farid the `url` was not working at that time I commented, eventually, the server throws 500 when it can't respond because of error.

Comment: You're talking about `500 Internal Server Error` OP's response is `Unexpected response code 500` it happens in client level, not in server level

Answer (score 1):

I have something
First import the okhttp inside the Gradle dependency (Library).
here is the documentation

https://square.github.io/okhttp/

After open the postman and click on the code menu [image]

As you can see below the send Button the code button is there. click it and select the java-> okhttp

copy the code and paste it inside android studio. it has 99.9 % chance it will work.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my project is bound to use Volley

Answer (score 0):

This error "500" means serverside error.This errors occurs in these case:-

1. May be wrong spell on the parameter or URLs
2. Lack of Parameter.
3. Or you are sending something that isn't accepted by Server.
4. Also Check "http:/" or"https:/" on Urls.

Check these conditions.I have also faced same problem .APIs are working on Post Man but not working on devices using volley. Hope this may help you.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan have check on the "Company_mobile" parameter if there any wrong?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan your parameter is not accepting the Server. Please check your server accepting key at once.

Comment: I have changed my php file and removed all params, still nothing

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Now,you have changed it in to GET Method.Then what are you getting error.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan I have just intgrated your api in demo and its working fine at myside.

Comment: Same...I have updated logcat, you can read that is says error code 500 for url

Comment: That is the issue, Postman is running the API normally but volley is throwing the error

Comment: The error you're referring to is `Internal server error`, OP's error is `Unexpected error` that means the problem is in the client level, not from the server.

Comment: @Farid Yes i am talking about Internal Server .

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all params you are trying to send are the same which server is expecting. Also wrong or missing parameters return 500 Error. 
Reverify this param `Company_mobile` in your request. Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status Codes starting with 5 inform that the error is on server side. The code 500 is interpreted as Internal Server Error, to solve this you have to check what might cause it. It may be caused by a mistake in the code in that case you can open your error_log to see the error and act accordingly.

It can be caused by server features being unavailable momently like accessing the database or having many simultaneous opened connections that exceed the associated mysql resources.

Some other times, the error is not logged into the error_log file. If you use a cpanel, at the homepage, under Metrics tab open Errors and check according to the time you requested to the server. If you are not using cpanel look for a corresponding server log.

follow this Right mark Answer.. it may help you

[How to deal with unexpected response 500 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242912/how-to-deal-with-unexpected-response-500-in-android)

Comment: let me check and I will let you know

Comment: Right now I checked response it is giving 200 OK Response

Comment: just change your content type text/html  to application/json

Comment: did but same response :'(

Comment: Everybody in this thread is talking about `Internal server error`,  OP gets  `Unexpected response` that means the problem is happening in a client not originating from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `db.php` file and then see variable that return object of connection.

I see it should be `$con->close()` with one n not `$conn->close()` with double n

Comment: While you have a good point, this should be a comment because while your right `$conn` should be `$con` it would not cause a 500 error because PHP will close the connection on its own after a timeout of not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try including in your php file :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I am not familliar with Kotlin but it is working fine for me using Java , here is the code :

```
private void loadRecyclerViewData2(){
        URR_DATA="http://squadtechsolution.com/android/v1/allcompany.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URR_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println("****"+response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("***"+error.getMessage());                    }
                });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Home.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And i get the following output :

```
I/System.out: ****
    [{"id":"1","company_name":"ABC","cuisine":"QATAR","conpany_phone":"4535345","company_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut ","company_logo":"company_logo5d80bac690f2e.png","company_type":"Food","delivery_type":"yes","delivery_range":"55","delivery_fee":"","delivery_pickupinfo":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, ","address":"33.58539655788556,71.43779296427965"}]
```

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Internet permission in your mafinest file ?

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Faizan ignore your doubts, the issue **`IS`** a 500 server error

**THIS IS THE CAUSE**

- POSTMAN and VOLLEY are not the same
- a) there is a bug in your PHP code `or` B) there is an environment setting that this exposes

**TO DIAGNOSE A PHP ISSUE**

and you need to open your `error_log` on php. Depending on your server this can be tricky to explain how so the other way is to change the `php.ini` to error_log to do this try this ON THE SERVER

([lifted from here deliberately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display#21429652))

```
/*This always works for me:*/

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*However, this doesn't make PHP to show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:*/

display_errors = on
/*(if you don't have access to php.ini, then putting this line in .htaccess might work too):*/

php_flag display_errors 1
```

**TO DIAGNOSE A ENVIRONMENT ISSUE ON SERVER**

If the `error_log` yields nothing try the `access_log`. Why? *Because it will probably show a different type of request has come in. and POSTMAN and VOLLEY are not the same*

You need to look at your `access_log` too potentially and watch it in real time as you click postman then click the volley client

**FACTS: (why we can be so sure)**

My gut says you have an issue in a wrongly configured server. Believe it or not the access_log will help you the most if this is the case.

Regardless: There is clearly an issue between what you are putting into POSTMAN and what your volley client is sending - that is causing this.

Things I have seen cause this include:

- It could be a `SAME ORIGIN` error.
- It could be a `INTERNAL SERVER REDIRECT` issue.
- It could be an imprecise forwarding of $_GET to $_POST (I have seen that issue on nginx)
- It could be a bad path issue that is being mangled with `no-redirect` and lack of security.

but without telling us the platform or the server (Windows? Linux? nginx? php-fpm? apache? etc) we can't get to help you on those

Comment: Thanks for your details explanation but as I am not a PHP developer, I can't completely understand everything, the PHP code above has been written by another person from freelance service

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan I suspected as much.. paste the code I gave you into the top of the `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and watch what it returns in POSTMAN and VOLLEY - also if it is a server config issue (as I suspect).. try to get on the server and watch the `access_log`

Comment: I will as a friend to do all this and will see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I am posting another answer If it is still unsolved.
In the postman copy all the headers like

```
.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
.addHeader("postman-token", "fa72f792-c9d3-7891-a544-f37f634f6ee1")
```

and put that in the volly params